# How to style label for="" element in CSS?

Tags: css

I have:

```
<label class="filter-label" for="pv[]181">
   ::before
   white
   <span class="count">5</span>
   ::after
</label>
```

Now I want to edit ::after element in that label, but it doesn't work. I tried:

```
.filter-label label[for="pv[]181"]::after
.filter-label label[for=pv[]181]::after
.filter-label[for=pv[]181]::after
```

How can I edit this `::after` element?

Thank you.

Comment: Just add quotes around your `pv[]181` in your last one

Comment: Or if you hate quotes, escape the brackets in the name, like `[for=pv\5b\5d 181]`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `label.filter-label[for="pv[]181"]::after` selector.

Your CSS selector (`.filter-label label[for="pv[]181"]::after`) was wrong. With your selector it was searching for a `label` element inside an element with class `filter-label`.

With my selector it means select a `label` with class `filter-label` and attribute value as desired.

```css
 
label.filter-label[for="pv[]181"]::after {
 content : "A";
 color: red;
}
label.filter-label[for="pv[]181"]::before {
 content : "B";
 color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<label class="filter-label" for="pv[]181">
   
   white
   <span class="count">5</span>
   
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vkxqmc4s/2/)

```css
label[for="pv[]181"]::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: red;
}

label[for="pv[]181"]::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<label class="filter-label" for="pv[]181">

   <span class="count">5</span>
   
</label>
```